# Failed ALPN negotiation: Unable to find compatible protocol

Tags: google-cloud-platform, certificate, google-cloud-certificate-authority

Im getting below error while working on my code.

Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: Failed ALPN negotiation: Unable to find compatible protocol

Channel Pipeline: [SslHandler#0, ProtocolNegotiators$ClientTlsHandler#0, WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler#0, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]

```
/*
 * Copyright 2021 Google LLC
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.demo.certificate;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.event.Level;

// [START privateca_create_ca]

import com.google.api.core.ApiFuture;
import com.google.cloud.security.privateca.v1.CaPoolName;
import com.google.cloud.security.privateca.v1.CertificateAuthority;
import com.google.cloud.security.privateca.v1.CertificateAuthority.KeyVersionSpec;
import com.google.cloud.security.privateca.v1.CertificateAuthority.SignHashAlgorithm;
import com.google.cloud.security.privateca.v1.CertificateAuthorityServiceClient;
import com.google.cloud.security.privateca.v1.CertificateConfig;
import com.google.cloud.security.privateca.v1.CertificateConfig.SubjectConfig;
import com.google.cloud.security.privateca.v1.CreateCertificateAuthorityRequest;
import com.google.cloud.security.privateca.v1.KeyUsage;
import com.google.cloud.security.privateca.v1.KeyUsage.KeyUsageOptions;
import com.google.cloud.security.privateca.v1.Subject;
import com.google.cloud.security.privateca.v1.X509Parameters;
import com.google.cloud.security.privateca.v1.X509Parameters.CaOptions;
import com.google.longrunning.Operation;
import com.google.protobuf.Duration;

public class CreateCertificateAuthority {

  public static void main(String[] args)
      throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, IOException {
    // TODO(developer): Replace these variables before running the sample.
    // location: For a list of locations, see:
    // https://cloud.google.com/certificate-authority-service/docs/locations
    // poolId: Set it to the CA Pool under which the CA should be created.
    // certificateAuthorityName: Unique name for the CA.
    String project = "corp-esgda-dev";
    String location = "us-east1";
    String poolId = "test-pool";
    String certificateAuthorityName = "myCA";
    createCertificateAuthority(project, location, poolId, certificateAuthorityName);
  }

  // Create Certificate Authority which is the root CA in the given CA Pool.
  public static void createCertificateAuthority(
      String project, String location, String poolId, String certificateAuthorityName)
      throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, IOException {
    // Initialize client that will be used to send requests. This client only needs to be created
    // once, and can be reused for multiple requests. After completing all of your requests, call
    // the `certificateAuthorityServiceClient.close()` method on the client to safely
    // clean up any remaining background resources.
    try (CertificateAuthorityServiceClient certificateAuthorityServiceClient =
        CertificateAuthorityServiceClient.create()) {
    
        
        System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
        System.out.println(System.getProperties()   );
      String commonName = "dev";
      String orgName = "qc";
      int caDuration = 100000; // Validity of this CA in seconds.
      
      
     
      // Set the type of Algorithm.
      KeyVersionSpec keyVersionSpec =
          KeyVersionSpec.newBuilder().setAlgorithm(SignHashAlgorithm.RSA_PKCS1_4096_SHA256).build();

      // Set CA subject config.
      SubjectConfig subjectConfig =
          SubjectConfig.newBuilder()
              .setSubject(
                  Subject.newBuilder().setCommonName(commonName).setOrganization(orgName).build())
              .build();

      //  Set the key usage options for X.509 fields.
      X509Parameters x509Parameters =
          X509Parameters.newBuilder()
              .setKeyUsage(
                  KeyUsage.newBuilder()
                      .setBaseKeyUsage(
                          KeyUsageOptions.newBuilder().setCrlSign(true).setCertSign(true).build())
                      .build())
              .setCaOptions(CaOptions.newBuilder().setIsCa(true).build())
              .build();

      // Set certificate authority settings.
      CertificateAuthority certificateAuthority =
          CertificateAuthority.newBuilder()
              // CertificateAuthority.Type.SELF_SIGNED denotes that this CA is a root CA.
              .setType(CertificateAuthority.Type.SELF_SIGNED)
              .setKeySpec(keyVersionSpec)
              .setConfig(
                  CertificateConfig.newBuilder()
                      .setSubjectConfig(subjectConfig)
                      .setX509Config(x509Parameters)
                      .build())
              // Set the CA validity duration.
              .setLifetime(Duration.newBuilder().setSeconds(caDuration).build())
              .build();

      // Create the CertificateAuthorityRequest.
      CreateCertificateAuthorityRequest certificateAuthorityRequest =
          CreateCertificateAuthorityRequest.newBuilder()
              .setParent(CaPoolName.of(project, location, poolId).toString())
              .setCertificateAuthorityId(certificateAuthorityName)
              .setCertificateAuthority(certificateAuthority)
              .build();

      // Create Certificate Authority.
      ApiFuture<Operation> futureCall =
          certificateAuthorityServiceClient
              .createCertificateAuthorityCallable()
              .futureCall(certificateAuthorityRequest);
      System.out.println("futureCall:"+futureCall);
      Operation response = futureCall.get();

      if (response.hasError()) {
        System.out.println("Error while creating CA !" + response.getError());
        return;
      }

      System.out.println(
          "Certificate Authority created successfully : " + certificateAuthorityName);
    }
  }
}
// [END privateca_create_ca]


Pom.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>certificate</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>certificate-demo</name>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
                <version>26.29.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-security-private-ca</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-monitoring</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-alpn-openjdk8-client</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.44.v20210927</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version> <!-- Use the latest version available -->
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.70</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.truth</groupId>
            <artifactId>truth</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that there is an issue during the ALPN process when establishing a gRPC connection. ALPN is used to negotiate the protocol that will be used for the connection, such as HTTP/2. This also can happen if the client and server are using different versions of gRPC, or if the server is not configured to support the protocol that the client is trying to use.

> [Alpn_protocols](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/v3/tls.proto#extensions-transport-sockets-tls-v3-commontlscontext)
> supplies the list of ALPN protocols that the listener should expose.
> In practice this is likely to be set to one of two values.There is no
> default for this parameter. If empty, Envoy will not expose ALPN.
>
> - “h2,http/1.1” If the listener is going to support both HTTP/2 and HTTP/1.1.
> - “http/1.1” If the listener is only going to support HTTP/1.1.

To resolve your issue, Try checking the below steps.

1. As per the [github link](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/7201), the problem might be due to the **man-in-the-middle proxy not supporting http/2**, which is required for gRPC.This may happen when http2 is not enabled in the [configuration](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-grpc/current/troubleshooting.html).
2. If you resolve the proxy issue and still have trouble with TLS negotiation.You should ensure that the client and server are using the same version of the gRPC library and that they are configured to use the same TLS protocol. You can also try disabling TLS on the server to see if that resolves the issue.
3. Also verify the firewall settings as it might be related to your company firewall blocking issue.
4. Make sure that the client and server are using compatible versions of gRPC.

It might be your enterprise environment where your server is running does not support ALPN and HTTP2. There is more information in gRPC's [troubleshooting](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/SECURITY.md#troubleshooting).

Comment: I've tried with java 8,911,17 versions and also with different versions of google-cloud-security-private-ca(2.34.0) , but it doesn't worked. I donno how to configure these h2,http/1.1 in my java code. Could you please help me

Comment: Can you check the [article](https://www.baeldung.com/jetty-http-2#:~:text=3.2.&text=Note%3A%20To%20enable%20HTTP%2F2,in%20Java%209%20or%20later.&text=Here%2C%20we%20can%20observe%20that,and%208444%20with%20HTTP%2F2.) written by Anshul Bansal which explains the use case of http/2 in Java environment and let me know if it is useful to you.